# Is this a reasonable non-compete for an independent contractor?

Tags: united-kingdom, independent-contractor

I am an independent contractor who was just awarded a full-time contract.   I am concerned about signing it.

**Non Compete -** The Contractor specifically agrees that for a period of **5 years after the termination of the Agreement**, the Contractor will not engage, directly or indirectly, either as proprietor, stockholder, partner,officer, contractor or otherwise, in the same or similar activities as were performed for the Client in any **business worldwide** where xxxxx are the primary or secondary target market.*

Non Compete - The Contractor specifically agrees that for a period of 5 years after the termination of the Agreement, the Contractor will not engage, directly or indirectly, either as proprietor, stockholder, partner, officer, contractor or otherwise, in the same or similar activities as were performed for the Client or any direct competitor to XXXXX,

** I have edited this.

Comment: What is your question? you state that you have concerns but what are you asking?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep The question is in the title

Comment: [Useful information](https://www.gabyhardwicke.co.uk/briefing-notes/restrictive-covenants/). I would certainly push back on the *worldwide* bit: you're in the US; does the company operate there? Five years seems excessive: what do they need to protect for five years that would not already be worth continuing to protect after six months?

Comment: I don't know anything about UK law on this topic but most countries have severe restrictions of what can and cannot be legally written in a non-compete agreement. This looks way over the top and not legal in various jurisdictions, so signing this would be harmless because it is not valid anyway. But get proper legal advice before you try something like that.

Comment: Depending on your legal jurisdiction, a non-compete term of 5 years may not be legally enforceable. Many legal jurisdictions put limits on time and geographical space that are considered enforceable. However, I would not bother looking into that; a clause like this demonstrates a sort of insanity and is enough of a red flag for me to decline to work with someone.

Comment: The company uses almost ALL independent contractors from what I can tell and most are working from the UK -a few in the USA. The holding company is in England - they do sell globally.

Comment: This is unreasonable, unenforceable,  ludicrous, and possibly fattening.  There are legions of lawyers in the USA alone who would fight this on principle alone.

Comment: This is the derivative root of unreasonable.  Unless this thing comes with a signing bonus in the $500K range, don't even lay your pen down on it, let alone sign it.

Comment: @Lynn what sort of "independent" contractor are you. and I am not sure what that even means in UK law? are  your using a PLC or an Umbrella - your not likely  to be outside IR35

Comment: Nope, not legal in the UK. Restriction must be "`reasonable`" in terms of time and distance. Ask a lawyer, who will tell you the same. Ask the company, who will tell you "this is just a standard contract that we give to everyone. We would never enforce that". Then walk away

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it's unreasonable, and there's no way I'd ever sign something like that.

If you decide to quit for any reason, or they boot you out for any reason, you then have a **5 year** period where you can't work for any company, anywhere in the world, doing any "similar activities" (for fear of legal ramifications.) Assuming this "activity" (coaching) is what you do for a living, I can't see how it would ever make sense to tie yourself into a contract that could have such dire consequences if you choose to leave.

You may choose to push back with a maximum time period of 6 months, if that would be acceptable to you. Even that's something you should think about carefully however, and don't be afraid to walk away if they won't budge.

Comment: Many states would find the non-compete unenforceable due to it effectively shutting the contractor out of the entire industry for an unreasonable period of time.

Comment: Why do you recommend 6 months?

Comment: @JRodge01 You may be correct, but personally, I wouldn't factor that into a decision. I'd certainly never advise signing anything on the basis that it's probably not enforceable.

Comment: @PlayerOne That's a more reasonable time period, IMHO. I personally wouldn't consider it, but I know people who would (on the basis that they have other work / savings that can bridge them over that 6 month gap if the worst came to the worst.)

Comment: @berry120 Oh, I didn't mean to imply to sign it!  I agree with your sentiment to never sign something you don't intend on abiding by.

Comment: @berry120 OK. I wouldn't sign it either (and haven't in the past). Personally I think that pushing back with "no non-compete clause at all" is a better choice.

Comment: @PlayerOne that is what just might be considered acceptable in uk law - though for a v senior staff  member \(director level) not just a "senior" programmer

Answer (score 1):

Strike that clause out, and send it back to them highlighting the requested change on the contract and in the cover letter. Be sure to carbon copy the hiring manager/client (instead of just HR).

If they refuse, ask for 80% of your salary during those five years

And yes, that clause may be completely unenforceable, but why should you put yourself in that kind of situation if you can avoid it. Eventually, you want to leave on good terms and with a good reference (not a lawsuit, whether it's frivolous or not).

*PS: I'm using that 80% figure because I believe I know what your profession is. For other professions, that are more technical or that are more difficult to move to a different industry, I would potentially ask for 150%, or 200%, or perhaps even more.*